# Web browser independent of IE

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I would like to make a web browser for my own use with various customizations. However, in VB6 the various web related control like `winsock`, `inet` fetch only html. Using `webbrowser` control is not the answer because it uses the same settings as windows IE. What I'd like to know is a control somewhat like the `webbrowser` but independent of windows IE setting. So that the changes made in IE wont effect my web browser. And also the `webbrowser` control does not have features such as blocking a specific image/CSS according to URL etc.

What I want to know is that if it’s not possible to do with VB6, is it possible with Visual Basic 2010 Express?

Comment: Ah, you're pursuing the *nix nightmare.  Where every program is responsible for figuring out the proper proxy configuration.  Buried in poorly documented config files, they all do it differently.  Curses.

Comment: "the various web related control like winsock, inet fetch only html" is rubbish. Wininet is the underlying engine for any HTTP/FTP/gopher, etc request from IE and many other apps. Winsock is the socket stack underlying both of these and deals with raw socket connections. it has no idea about HTTP, let alone HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`winsock` is a general purpose socket library and can communicate over the Internet to get all sort of data, not just HTML. And that's the answer to your question. If for some reason you want to create your own browser, you need to start from `winsock`.

Also, Visual Basic 2010 Express is the name of a particular version of IDE which is used to build programs in VB.NET which is the replacement for VB6. In conclusion, you can build your browser in either VB6 or VB.NET, however, I would recommend VB.NET as Microsoft has retired VB6 as a product and a technology.

Comment: "has retired" is an understatement. VB6 is unsupported.

Comment: @John I have a soft spot for VB6. Retired sounds dignified - unsupported sounds, well, melancholy I guess :).

Comment: If someone is thinking about using a VB6 application in production, then "unsupported" is what they need to hear.

Comment: Yeah unsupported.  That's why the runtimes have been a part of the OS from 98SE up through and including Windows 8 developer preview.  Right.

Comment: There is a difference between the IDE being supported (not since March 2008) and the runtime being supported (commitments to ensure it continues to run on OSes through win server 2008). Here is the official MS word on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708